# Выборы модератора сообщества 2017

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, выборы

В настоящее время проводятся выборы модераторов сообщества 2017!
Выборы модераторов сообщества состоят из трёх этапов:

1. Этап выдвижения кандидатур
2. Этап предварительных выборов
3. Этап выборов

Обычно процесс выборов занимает от 2 до 3 недель, но всё зависит от количества кандидатов.

Пожалуйста, посетите официальную страницу выборов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election для получения дополнительной информации и принимайте участие!

Если у вас есть вопросы по процессу проведения выборов или по кандидатам в модераторы, задавайте их здесь, на Мете — только убедитесь, что ваши вопросы имеют метку [выборы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b).